# Select weekends and weekdays by weekday() in python

Tags: python, datetime, timestamp, weekday

I have the following data:

```
2010-01-01 00:00:00 327
2010-01-01 01:00:00 237
2010-01-01 02:00:00 254
...
```

I can select different data by month but I would like to select data from weekdays and data from weekends. How could it be possible to do it by using weekday function?  I have performed something like this but it does not work.

```
data['Month'] = data['Timestamp'].dt.month
summer = (data.Month >=6) & (data.Month <=8) 
data['WEEKDAY'] = ((pd.DatetimeIndex(data.index).dayofweek) // 5 == 1).astype(float)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
data['WEEKDAY'] = data.Timestamp.dt.dayofweek
```

0 is Monday.
Next mark weekends as 1 in column `WEEKEND`:

```
data['WEEKEND'] = np.where(data.Timestamp.dt.dayofweek.isin([5,6]), 1, 0)
```

To separate into 2 dataframes:

```
weekends = data[data['WEEKEND']==1]
workdays = data[data['WEEKEND']!=1]
```

Comment: but, how could it be possible to select only the weekdays for 200 rows (the first column corresponds to the timestamp)? Thanks a lot

Comment: Just: `data.loc[data['WEEKEND']==0,:].head(200)`. BTW What does it mean to select weekdays?

Comment: Just to make a new dataframe 'weekday' with data cooresponding from Monday to Friday and a new data frame with only the days from the weekends. Is os correct:?```weekday = (data.WEEKDAY >=0) & (data.WEEKDAY <=4) weekend = (data.WEEKEND <=5) & (data.WEEKEND <=6)```

Comment: I've updated answer. Please consider accepting it as a solution.